# How to refactor all cjs files to es6 modules in all files of a project or directory? (vscode)

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ecmascript-6, vim, es6-modules

have a projcet with cjs requires like this :

```
const express = require("express")
```

I want to refactor them all to es6 imports :

```
import express from "express"
```

in Vscode, in every single file, a 3 dotted line appears under first require, if you press Ctrl+. it will suggest you `convert to es6 module`

like this [image: this]

so repeating this process in all files of a legacy project looks unnecessary, how to convert all files to es6 in Vscode?

any other automated method or editor(other than Vscode like Vim) would be appreciated

Comment: [Why use a text editor for that at all](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cjs-to-es6)?

Comment: @romainl do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you consider clicking on the link? It's not a rick roll.